# How do I find an expectation value for an electron's magnetic moment?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, angular-momentum, quantum-spin, bloch-sphere

Given a spin state:
$|s\rangle$ = some linear combination of $|\uparrow\rangle + |\downarrow\rangle$  possibly with an imaginary component. How do you get from the definition of a magnetic momentum operator $\hat{\mu}_e = g\mu_B\hat{\sigma}$ to the expectation value of the electron spin magnetic moment?

$g$ is the gyrmoagnetic factor and is approximately 2.0023.

$\mu_B =\frac{e\hbar}{2m_o}$ is the Bohr magneton.

$\hat{\sigma}$ is the Pauli spin matrix.

I feel like this is the operation

$\langle s| \hat{\mu}_e |s\rangle$

If it is, I need an example walk-through with some arbitrary complex $|s\rangle$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let
$$|s\rangle = \alpha|\uparrow\rangle + \beta|\downarrow\rangle$$
We assume that $s$ is normalized i.e. $\langle s | s\rangle = 1 \implies |\alpha|^2+|\beta|^2 = 1$.
Then the expectation value of $\hat{\mu}_e$ is:
$$\langle\hat{\mu}_e\rangle = \langle s|\hat{\mu}_e|s\rangle$$
$$\implies \langle\hat{\mu}_e\rangle = |\alpha|^2\langle\uparrow| \hat{\mu}_e |\uparrow\rangle + |\beta|^2\langle\downarrow| \hat{\mu}_e |\downarrow\rangle + \alpha^{\ast}\beta\langle\uparrow| \hat{\mu}_e |\downarrow\rangle + \alpha\beta^{\ast}\langle\downarrow| \hat{\mu}_e |\uparrow\rangle$$
Now, $\hat{\mu}_e = g\mu_B\hat{\sigma}$. We use this together with $\langle \uparrow|\hat{\sigma}|\uparrow\rangle = 1$, $\langle \downarrow|\hat{\sigma}|\downarrow\rangle = -1$, and $\langle \uparrow|\hat{\sigma}|\downarrow\rangle = \langle \downarrow|\hat{\sigma}|\uparrow\rangle = 0$, to get:
$$\langle\hat{\mu}_e\rangle = g\mu_B(|\alpha|^2 - |\beta|^2)$$
Note that this expression for the expectation value is consistent with interpreting $|\alpha|^2$ and $|\beta|^2$ as probabilities of finding the spin to be $\uparrow$ and $\downarrow$ respectively, as required.

Comment: What happens if we have two $\uparrow$ spins with $\alpha$ being real and $\beta$ being imaginary?

Comment: The result is applicable for general complex coefficients. Two $\uparrow$ spin terms with different coefficients would just add up to one $\uparrow$ spin term with the (complex) sum of the coefficients. But it is only $\uparrow$ and $\downarrow$ together that describe all possible spin states.

Comment: Ah, I could just consider it $\alpha= x+ yi $ and $\beta= 0$ and it would apply to a specific observation. Yes?

Comment: Or would only having  $\uparrow$ mean that the result is a vector?

Comment: You can take $\alpha = x + iy$ and $\beta = 0$.

Comment: Note: I had assumed that $\hat{\sigma}$ in the question was the spin operator in the direction of $\uparrow$ and $\downarrow$. The overall method is similar if it refers to a vector, as apparently indicated in this later question: http://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/177709/